# Converting Dict Keys and Searching Them

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dict that's like

```
dict1 = {'Lou': ['Male', '15', '2'],'Jen':['Female','10','3']...and more}
```

Im trying to search for values greater than 14 in the 2nd part of the list and then print out the key/value.  I understand that I have to convert the strings to an integer and I believe I have to iterate by doing a dict1.values method however I'm unsure of how to specify the 2nd value in the list.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dict1.items` to iterate through key and values at the same time:

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
    if int(value[1]) > 14:
        print key, value
```

For each `value` you get the second part with `value[1]`, you convert it to an integer with `int` and then you perform your check. When the check is successful, we print both key and value, as we have access to them.

Answer (score 2):

You could use dict_comprehension.

```
>>> dict1 = {'Lou': ['Male', '15', '2'],'Jen':['Female','10','3']}
>>> {x:y for x,y in dict1.items() if int(y[1]) > 14}
{'Lou': ['Male', '15', '2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `dict.items` it will give you a tuple containing key/value pair.

Using `filter` and `lambda`:

```
>>> my_dict = {'Lou': ['Male', '15', '2'],'Jen':['Female','10','3']}
>>> filter(lambda x:int(x[1][1])>14, my_dict.items())
[('Lou', ['Male', '15', '2'])]
```

using Keys:

```
>>> {x:my_dict[x] for x in my_dict if int(my_dict[x][1])>14}
{'Lou': ['Male', '15', '2']}
```